# Scrape jenkins metrics with prometheus

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I'm new to Prometheus, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but these are my service and service monitor definitions.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: '8080'
    prometheus.io/path: '/prometheus'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: jenkins
    app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: jenkins
```

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: jenkins
    app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins
    release: prometheus
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 10s
    path: /prometheus/
    port: "8080"
  jobLabel: app.kubernetes.io/instance
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: jenkins
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: jenkins
```

But my Jenkins doesn't appear under the targets list on the Prometheus UI.
It appears under `Service Discovery` which makes me believe that the Operator is correctly picking it up through the `release: prometheus` label.

I have installed the `prometheus plugin` on jenkins and I'm able to view metrics when I curl `https://<JENKINS_URL>/prometheus/`

What I'm trying to figure out is why Jenkins doesn't appear under the `targets` list.

Is there any proper documentation on how to go about this or can anyone who has successfully implemented this share any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better docs than reading the code itself.

You need pay attention to [this line in the custom resource definition of ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/master/manifests/setup/prometheus-operator-0servicemonitorCustomResourceDefinition.yaml#L140).

```yaml
port:
  description: Name of the service port this endpoint refers to.
               Mutually exclusive with targetPort.
  type: string
```

Basically, you created a serviceMonitor to a service port named "8080".

```yaml
endpoints:
  - interval: 10s
    path: /prometheus/
    port: "8080"
```

But you defined an unnamed service whose port number is 8080.

```yaml
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

Do you see the mismatch now?

You need
either use targetPort: 8080 and targetPort only in serviceMonitor,

or, even better, use port: "web" in serviceMonitor, and at the same time, name your service "web".

ServiceMonitor:

```yaml
endpoints:
  - interval: 10s
    path: /prometheus/
    port: "web"
```

Service:

```yaml
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: "web"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add annotations to your pod :)

```
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/path: /prometheus
      prometheus.io/port: '8080'
      prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
```

Comment: Hi Florian, I've added this in already, but I'm unable to get it to work. I'll update the question with my actual definitions so that it's clearer.